# Footer in latex

Tags: header-footer

I am having a problem in footer. I want to add header footer in every page of my document but the header is appearing on every page but footer isn't.

Please provide me some solution.

I am using `\cfoot`/`\chead` commands for headers and footers.

Comment: thanks will do so as soon as amazon delivers my crystal ball -- is there an existing code or is it in the `cloud`

Comment: we cant help you without knowing what you did. pleas provide some code

Comment: I sort out  my problem. Actually I was using geometry package. So I fixed out the margins. Actually the footer comes down out of the page